# How to extract from this list of tuples and convert into this dictionary?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have this list of tuples.

```
List = [('id1', 'name1', 'date1'), ('id1', 'name2', 'date2'), ('id2', 'name3', 'date3'), ('id2', 'name4', 'date4')]
```

I want to have a function that converts list to become a dictionary such that

```
Dict = convert('id1', List)
```

Contents of Dict is `{'id1':('name1', 'name2')}`

The first parameter filters out the tuples that are of interest based on the first element. It is also the key of the output dictionary. The 2nd element of each tuple will become the values of the output dictionary.

I wrote a little function in Python and it does not work. Thank you very much for your help if you have better suggestions. Forget about my function if it is too far out which I think so. Solving it in a pythonic way is most welcome. I am using Python 2.7

```
def convertToDict(key, List):
    for key in List[0]:
        DictOut = {key:[]}
        DictOut[key].append(List[0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the `DictOut` unconditionally. Instead you should be using `setdefault` like this

```
DictOut.setdefault(key, [])
```

Your program can be written like this

```
def convertToDict(my_list):
    result_dict = {}
    for item in my_list:
        result_dict.setdefault(item[0], []).append(item[1])
    return result_dict

print convertToDict(my_list)
# {'id2': ['name3', 'name4'], 'id1': ['name1', 'name2']}
```

If you want to get only the specific keys. you can use this

```
def convertToDict(key, my_list):
    result_dict = {}
    for item in my_list:
        if item[0] == key:
            result_dict.setdefault(item[0], []).append(item[1])
    return result_dict

print convertToDict("id1", my_list)
# {'id1': ['name1', 'name2']}
```

You can actually use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this purpose, like this

```
from collections import defaultdict
def convertToDict(key, my_list):
    result_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for item in my_list:
        if item[0] == key:
            result_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])
    return result_dict

print convertToDict("id1", my_list)
```

Comment: I was only expecting one answer but you gave me several great answers!! Unfortunately, I can only upvote you once. Thanks!!